# Backend implementation for backbone js in Java

Tags: java, rest, backbone.js

I am using **Backbone JS** for front end, which in turn uses Rest protocol to make calls to backend on server. So what will be the correct way to implement backend code in **Java**?

Do I need a web-service implementation on my server for this or I can manage with Servlets? If I am able to manage with servlets, any pointers on that will be really useful for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 big frameworks I am aware of - all of them are implementations of JAX-RS

- RESTeasy
- Jersey
- Jackson

Of course you can do it by hand (servlets), but:

1. you'll make a lot of mistakes
2. it will be hard
3. code will be incredibly hard to mantain

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should implement REST api. It will be convenient for your application. Backbone.sync is there to make call to REST services.

Have a look : 
http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Sync